# array loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects.

When I push a new object into my parent function, I want it to:

- check if the object already exists in the array
- If it does, check if the value of that object has changed
- If it has, update the object
- If it hasn't, just leave the object as it is

Otherwise:

- If the object doesnt exist, push it into the array

This sounds simple enough and my logic seems to be right in my head but I cant seem to get it to do as outlined above, it instead, upon trying to update a property by passing an object with the same key as one that is in the array already as a parameter to the function, overwrites its new value AND pushes a new copy....., here is the relevant code:

```js
var filters = [];

function addFilterToFiltersArray(obj) {
  var isValidFilter,
    filterKey = "",
    filterEnglishReadable = "",
    hasBeenAjaxed;

  for (var prop in knownFilters) {
    //is the filter a valid key in the knownFilters object?
    if (obj.key === prop) {
      //if so set it as valid and create a variable to hold the key and another for the value
      isValidFilter = true,
        filterKey = prop,
        filterEnglishReadable = knownFilters[prop];

      //check if the filters array has elements in it
      if (filters.length > 0) {
        //if it does, loop the array
        for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
          //check if any of the array objects have a key that matches the pushed filter
          console.log(obj)
          if (filters[i].key === obj.key) {
            console.log('keys are equal, update', filters[i].key, obj.key)
              //if it does, check if the value has changed in the newly pushed version
            if (filters[i].value === obj.value) {
              //if the value has not changed, it is in the array and there is no update necessary
              hasBeenAjaxed = true;
            } else {
              //otherwise we overwrite the value with the new value
              filters[i].value = obj.value;
              //since we have now updated the value of the object in the filters array
              //we not set the hasBeenAjaxed variable to false so that ajax runs with the new value
              hasBeenAjaxed = false;
            }
          } else {
            console.log('keys are not equal, push', filters[i].key, obj.key, obj)
              //otherwise, the filter key is not in the array and so we set the hasBeenAjaxed variable as such
            hasBeenAjaxed = false;
            filters.push(obj);
          }
        }
      } else {
        //in this case, the array is empty and thus we can assume that the filter isnt there, obviously.
        hasBeenAjaxed = false;
        filters.push(obj);
      }
      //if the value was updated, the filter wasnt found in the above loop, we push the new value/key-value and run ajax
      if (hasBeenAjaxed === false) {
        //ajax
        //pass to the dom builder
        addFilterToDOM(filterEnglishReadable);
      }
    } else {
      //otherwise its not valid
      isValidFilter = false;
      filterEnglishReadable = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Perhaps I am just missing something minor, but yeah, any ideas?

Comment: please add some data, like the arrays.

Comment: Just updated the post with how to replicate. Just insert an object into the array with any key and value `{key: "key", value: "value"}` and then pass the same object to the function with a new value and look at the console logs. Also read my update which says what exactly is happening.

Comment: You don't have to loop through `knownFilters` to see if the object key is known. Just test `obj.key in knownFilters` - if that's `true` then the key is in there.

Comment: Also, I don't see any code that adds the `obj.key` value to the `knownFilters` object when you push a new object onto the list.

Comment: I dont push to the known filters array, that is a reference object of all filters I will accept, whereas the filters array is where the key value pairs of accepted filters go. I think you misunderstood my question or a little? As for the obj.key in knownFilters bit, that makes sense, will update that, but the functionality is what needs looked at still.